# how to write query for checking list contains

Tags: python, django

I have a model with name Weekdays that contain a field with name Days. Days is a list of weekdays that already saved.
ex:

```
Days=['Monday', 'Sunday', 'Saturday']
```

there is a Variable in my view.py with name selected_day.
ex:

```
selected_day=['Monday']
```

now I want to find the object that Days field includes selected_day and I need to write a query that checks is Days contain selected_day or not.

something like this maybe:

```
my_obj=models.Weekdays.objects.get(Days contain selected_day)
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a `CharField` or `TextField` for storing that list you could do something like this:

```
objs = MyModel.objects.filter(Days__contains=selected_day)
```

Also see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#contains).

Answer (score 0):

That's what you 'are looking for:

```
my_obj=Weekdays.objects.filter(Days__contains=selected_day)
```

Comment: `Days` is the list and `selected_day` is a single value, so this won't work for the given case.

Comment: @wfehr exactly. You check a single value to a list not the opposite. In the given example you need to check if `Monday` is in `'Monday', 'Sunday', 'Saturday'` not if `'Monday', 'Sunday', 'Saturday'` is in `Monday` obviously it is not.

Comment: The model field is `Days`, not `selected_day`. Therefore you aren't able to perform a query like `selected_day__in=...`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
Days=['Monday', 'Sunday', 'Saturday']
selected_day=['Monday']

my_obj=models.Weekdays.objects.get(selected_day__in=Days)
```

It will return you the objects of your selected days.

**EDIT**

```
objs = MyModel.objects.filter(Days__contains=selected_day)
```

This query is perfect since Days is the Model Field.

Comment: The model field is `Days`, not `selected_day`. That's why you can't perform the query given in this answer.

Comment: Why negative voting ??

Comment: Because your answer is wrong. You just edited it after another person gave the correct answer.

Comment: I updated answers after discussion in comments and later on comments were deleted too!